# Securing your Heroku database

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I currently have a back end hosted on Heroku, at the minute the data is open and anyone *could* access it. Is there a way to add some form of authentication to this? For example, if I use an API I am required to use an API key in order to access the data.

I currently have a 'Hobby' database but appreciate i may need to pay a subscription for additional features.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the minute the data is open and anyone _could_ access it"? Heroku Postgres databases require a password to access. Or do you mean that _your back-end_ is open and anybody could access it? Your back-end code and your database are different things.

Comment: Yeah, apologies for the wording. The database is PostgreSQL and is hosted on Heroku, when I go to the url all the data is displayed in Json form. I am wondering if there is a way to "lock" this down.

Comment: Heroku doesn't do this for you. You need to add support for it in your application. How you do that depends on a whole bunch of things and is far too broad and opinion-based to be on-topic here.

Comment: I see, no problem. Thanks for the response

Comment: The URL itself is how your database is locked down. It contains the three portions required for access: 1) your password, 2) your username, and 3) the database name. As such, the URL should be treated same as any other secret token.